# What's the difference between these two ways of declaring a self binding?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding

I have an UserControl containing a *ItemsSource* DependenceProperty that has to be binded to the ItemsSource property of an internal Control:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

vs

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource, ElementName=controlName}"
```

controlName is the name of the control.

The first binding is not working while the second one works. I don't get the difference.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MultiSelectTreeView.MultiSelectableTreeView"

         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 

         mc:Ignorable="d"

         Name="multiTree" >

This does not work ---> <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" >
This works ---> <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource, ElementName=multiTree}" >
```

Comment: Is 'controlName` name of your UserControl?

Comment: Updated the answer. Can you try with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to bind to DP of parent UserControl, you need to bind it using `Mode = FindAncestor`. Since you are binding on internal control, you need to travel up the Visual Tree.

`Self Mode` will search for DP in internal control and not on parent UserControl.

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                                   AncestorType=UserControl}}"
```

Comment: Now I get you, Self refers to the TreeView itself, not it's parent.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming from your question that you have Xaml that is something like this in structure:

```
<UserControl x:Name="rootElement">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding .....}" />
</UserControl>
```

Your bindings are then doing the following:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

... this will look for the property `ItemsSource` on the control that the binding is declared on (that is, the `ListBox`).  In your case this will cause a problem because you're essentially setting up an infinite recursion: your `ItemsSource` is bound to the `ItemsSource` is bound to the... ad infinitum.  You mention that you're working with a `UserControl` here, and I suspect that you might be expecting `RelativeSource` to return the root `UserControl` element - but this is not the case.

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource, ElementName=rootElement}"
```

... this will bind to the property `ItemsSource` on the control with a specific name.  If you're working in a `UserControl` then typically you would have set `x:Name` on the root element of the `UserControl` and would be referring to it from a binding in this way.  This would allow you to bind the child `ListBox` to the public `ItemsSource` property of your `UserControl`.

Just for information, one other alternative is to use an `AncestorType` binding to find your parent `UserControl`.  If your `UserControl` type is called `MyControl`, it would look something like this:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=MyControl}}"
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem I had is that when I used Self I thought Self was the container control instead of the control where the binding was set. Thanks for your help.